# How do I get gson.toJson to work correctly for 'Size' class objects on SdkVersion 28?

Tags: android, gson

When I changed SdkVersion from 27 to 28, the result of gson.toJson of 'Size' class objects became empty.
Further examination, in the case of Sdk Version 28, the emulator of API 26 gives correct results.
However, it turned out that the result is empty in the emulator of API28.
Please tell me how to operate normally with SdkVersion 28.

--build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

--source code

```
import android.util.Size;

Gson gson = new Gson();
Size s = new Size(30,40);
Log.d("TAG", "s " + gson.toJson(s));
```

--Log of emulator (Android 8.0.0, API26)

```
2019-03-29 20:00:01.375 6212-6212/com.example.test D/TAG: s {"mHeight":40,"mWidth":30}
```

--Log of emulator (Android 9, API28)

```
2019-03-29 20:03:40.310 8152-8152/com.example.test D/TAG: s {}
```

Comment: Could you show how `Size` class looks like?

Comment: @Michał Ziober 'Size' class is 'android.util.Size'.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I solved it by adding custom serialization.

```
    private class SizeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Size> {
        public JsonElement serialize(Size src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("mHeight", src.getHeight());
            jsonObject.addProperty("mWidth", src.getWidth());
            return jsonObject;
        }
    }
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Size.class, new SizeSerializer())
            .create();
```

I do not know if this is the correct response or if there is a problem with sdk.